# how to access sub? urls keeping the main url connection alive

Tags: python, linux, curl, cookies, http-headers

trying to access some sub? php urls/endpoints to get overall h/w health status. Problem here is I could able to access only from browser those urls/endpoints with long cookies. when i try with python and linux cmd line getting 401 error

url_login_page=https://10.10.10.10/designs/imm/index.php

below are the available php's I wanted to access with python & curl, and able view the content of these php's from browser without issues

```
{"home.php":"1"},{"event-log.php":"4"},{"event-notification.php":"5"},
{"event-notification.php":"5"},{"service-problems.php":"6"},{"servicesettings.php":"7"},{"download-service-data.php":"8"},{"serverfirmware.php":"9"},{"remote-control.php":"10"},
{"server-properties.php":"11"},{"server-actions.php":"12"},{"fanlist.php":"13"},
{"power-modules.php":"14"},{"disk-list.php":"15"},{"memorylist.php":"16"},
{"cpu-list.php":"17"},{"server-timeouts.php":"18"},{"immproperties.php":"19"},
{"user-list.php":"20"},{"network-properties.php":"21"},{"immsecurity.php":"22"},
{"backup-restore.php":"23"},{"pxe-network-boot.php":"28"},{"osfailurescreen.php":"29"},{"feature-on-demand.php":"80"}]
```

UPDATED

Now I able to get the cookies value and headers with requests,

```
import requests

>>> headers = {
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Referer': 'https://10.10.10.10/designs/imm/index.php',
    'Origin': 'https://10.10.10.10',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

>>> data = {
  'user': 'user',
  'password': 'pass',
  'SessionTimeout': '1200'
}

>>> response = requests.post('https://10.10.10.10/data/login', headers=headers, data=data)



>>> response.text
u'{"status":"ok","authResult":"0","TimeWait":"0","iteSrc":"0","forwardUrl":"index-console.php",
"redirection":"home.php","token1_name":"ST17A1FA74B","token1_value":"FF7A4A9934170D1E",
"token2_name":"ST25220A3EA","token2_value":"A547237AA8EB5709",
"token3_name":"ST3FD5CF3C9","token3_value":"C97E95BB2097CA95","errorMsg":""}'


>>> response.headers
{'Content-length': '318', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self';
connect-src 'self' ws://*:3900/ wss://*:3900/; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:", 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 
'Set-Cookie': '_appwebSessionId_=24eb46d3ec26bef7efc9b754f8c79548; 
 path=/; httponly; secure', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;', 
'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=60, max=2000',
'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
'Cache-control': 'no-cache="set-cookie"',
'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-type': 'text/json'}


response.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='_appwebSessionId_', value='24eb46d3ec26bef7efc9b754f8c79548',
port=None, port_specified=False, domain='10.10.10.10', domain_specified=False, 
domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, 
secure=True, expires=None, discard=True, 
comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'httponly': None}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

The problem is I tried with token values and session ID to access sub urls and getting 401 error.

```
url1 = 'https://10.10.10.10/designs/imm/dataproviders/imm_status_hardware.php'
>>> resp = requests.post(url1, headers=response.headers, cookies=response.cookies, data=data, verify=False)
>>> resp
<Response [401]>
>>>
```

I'm sure not trying in a proper way the headers and cookies

Please help me how could i access the sub urls?

Comment: Would be useful if you listed all the cookies that the relevant website stores on the browser.

Comment: could you please provide here r.headers ?

Comment: did you getting the session and using it?

Comment: I've updated new findings

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [sessions with the Request](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) library?
I recall having used it in a scenario similar to yours to retain a session in which I issued multiple requests where subsequent requests required certain cookie(s) to be present or else they would fail.

Comment: I updated my findings able to get the response for headers and cookies, when using the token/sessions id to access sub url ending up with 401 error

Answer (score -1):

You've already received the response in the JSON format. Just extract it using the json library in Python.

```
import json
```

Then extract the Request r by:

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
```

The data variable will have all tuples which were extracted by the request.